# Translating statement on complex projective space to regular $2$-sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers

I'm working on a completely geometric construction of the Hopf-fibration of $S^3$ in an undergraduate context. It is completely possible to explain the construction and why it must be non-trivial to someone who only took introductory differential geometry with a bit of topology.

*Actually giving trivializing maps is seemingly always ignored when doing this construction though.* I want to fill precisely this hole, as I personally feel the Hopf-fibration can be an excellent and beautiful "motivating" example for undergrads going on to the graduate level.

In multiple places, I have found maps that trivialize over the complex projective plane instead of $S^2$, e.g. [page two of this](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/%7Ewangzuoq/Courses/16F-Manifolds/Notes/Lec15.pdf).

I am frankly overwhelmed by the notation and assumptions they use.

To do the intuitive geometric construction, I used quaternions, where the Hopf-map is then given by
$$h: S^3\subset\mathbb H\rightarrow S^2, r\mapsto ri\bar r$$
and I have the corresponding parameterizations of the Hopf-fibers over any given point.

The linked resource calls the Hopf-map $\pi$ and defines an open cover of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ as
$$U_j=\{[z^1:z^2]\vert z_j\ne 0\}, j=1,2.$$
On these domains, it then gives the trivializations
$$\Phi_j:\pi^{-1}(U_j)\rightarrow U_j\times S^1, z\mapsto\left([z^1:z^2], \frac{z^j}{\lvert z^j\rvert}\right).$$
From what I know about the complex projective plane, I think it should be possible to translate these statements into statements on $S^2$, perhaps even with a **geometric interpretation**. $U_j$ would be a cover of $S^2$ and instead of talking about two complex numbers, we would be talking about one quaternion.

Is this possible? What would $[z^1:z^2]$ mean in this context, and what is the geometric interpretation?

Comment: To be clear, are you identifying $S^2$ with the set of purely imaginary quaternions of norm 1?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes, exactly

Comment: I disagree with your implied assertion that the quaternion description is geometric, while the description using $\mathbb{CP}^1$ isn't. For me, the description of the Hopf fibration as a map $S^3 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ is very clear geometrically. You send a point $z \in S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ to the complex line through $z$ and the origin ($\mathbb{CP}^1$ is the space of lines through the origin in $\mathbb{C}^2$). On the other hand, the description via quaternions is less geometric (to me).

Comment: Having said that, you can use the trivialisations over $\mathbb{CP}^1$ to construct trivialisations in your setting. I don't have time to write out the details, but the idea is to compose stereographic projection $S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with the identification $\mathbb{R}^2\to U_1$ given by $(x, y)\mapsto[1,x+iy]$, and likewise for $S^2\setminus\{(0,0,-1)\}$ and $U_2$. Then you can use the trivialisations over $U_1$ and $U_2$ to construct trivialisations over $S^2$. You will then have to use the identification with quaternions if you are determined to use that description.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I didn't intend that assertion, as I (as an undergrad) don't know enough about complex projective space to make it. Thank you for your hint on how to apply stereographic projection. Could you please tell me what the colon notation in the first component means though?

Comment: The expressions $[z_1 : z_2]$ and $[z_1, z_2]$ denote [homogenous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). In particular, $[\lambda z_1: \lambda z_2] = [z_1 : z_2]$ for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$.

Comment: In the hope of bridging a gap: A quaternion $a + bi + cj + dk = (a + bi) + (c + di)j$ may be identified with the ordered pair of complex numbers $(a + bi, c + di) = (z_1, z_2)$. The homogeneous coordinates Michael mentions are effectively ratios because wherever the fractions are defined we have$$[z_1:z_2] = [1:z_2/z_1] = [z_1/z_2:1].$$

Comment: Just a few minor cosmetic points. You should be writing $\Bbb CP^1$, not $\Bbb CP^n$, and this is the complex projective *line*, NOT projective *plane* (that's $\Bbb CP^2$).

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$

Part of the story goes something like this:

There is, by the definition of complex projective space, a natural surjection $$\mathbb{C}^2\backslash\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1.$$ Given $(z_0,z_1) \in \C\backslash\{0\}$, $[z_0,z_1]$ is the notation used for its image under this map. Clearly, if you restrict this map to $S^3 = \{ |z_0|^2 +|z_1|^2=1\}$, it is still surjective. Moreover, the inverse image of any point in $\C P^1$ is easily seen to be a circle.

The map $$[z_0,z_1] \mapsto (1, z_1/z_0)$$ is radial projection and a bijection from $\C P^1$ minus a point to a $2$-dimensional affine plane. There is a second one $$[z_0,1]\mapsto (z_0/z_2, 1)$$
This defines two coordinate charts that cover $\C P^1$. If you compute the transition map from coordinate chart to the other, it turns out to be the same formula as the transition maps for stereographic coordinates of the unit sphere. This is one way to show that $\C P^1$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere.